# Classify finitely generated modules over the ring $\mathbb{C}[\epsilon]$ where $\epsilon^2=0$

Tags: modules, abelian-groups

Classify finitely generated modules over the ring $\mathbb{C}[\epsilon]$ where $\epsilon^2=0$

Since $\mathbb{C}[x]$ s noetherian we have that $\mathbb{C}[x]/(x^2)$ is too. And thus finitely generated $\mathbb{C}[\epsilon]$ modules are also finitely presented.

I'm not sure where to go from here. I imagine I need to use the fact that $\epsilon$ is not a unit.

Also, how would this problem be different if it were over $\mathbb{C}[i]$ instead. Obviously, here $i$ is a unit.

Comment: Note that $\mathbb{C}[\epsilon]$ is also artinian.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A module  over the ring $R=\mathbb C[\epsilon]/(\epsilon^2)$ is the same thing as a pair $(M,f)$ with $M$ a complex vector space and $f:M\to M$ a linear map such that $f\circ f=0$. Indeed:

- to each $R$-module $M$ we can assign the pair $(V,f)$ with $V=M$, the underlaying compex vector space of $M$, and $f:v\in V\mapsto \epsilon v\in V$,
- and to each pair $(V,f)$ we can asign the $R$-module $M$ which coincides with $V$ as a complex vector space and where multiplication by $\epsilon$ is given by $\epsilon\cdot v=f(v)$ for all $v\in M$.

One can easily check that these two assignemnts are mutually inverse. To classify $R$-modules, then, it is enough to classify pairs $(V,f)$ as above and then translate the result using the second assignment.

The classification of finitely generated $R$-modules is therefore equivalent to the theory of Jordan canonical forms of nilpotent endomorphisms of vector spaces of nilpotentcy index $2$. The non-finitely generated case can in fact be dealt with in exactly the same way, and we this get the result rschwieb mentions that *all* modules are direct sum of f.g. ones.

**The end result is as follows:**  suppose $M$ is an $R$-module; it is canonically a complex vector space, and we use this structure below. Pick a basis $B$ of the subspace $\epsilon M$, for each $b\in B$ let $b'\in M$ be an element such that $\epsilon b'=b$, let $B'=\{b':b\in B\}$ and let $C$ be a basis of subspace of $V$ complementary to the subspace generated by $B\cup B'$. Then you can check that $B\cup B'\cup C$ is a $\mathbb C$-basis of $M$, that the subspaces $F$ and $Z$ spanned by $B\cup B'$ and $C$, respectively, are an $R$-submodule, and that $M=F\oplus Z$ as $R$-modules.

Moreover, you can check that $Z$ is a direct sum of $|C|$ copies of the $1$-dimensional $R$-module $S=R/(\epsilon)$, and that $F$ is a direct sum of $|B|$ copies of the free $R$-module of rank one $R$.

Wrapping it up, we see that every $R$-module is a direct sum of some number of copies of the $1$-dimensional $R$-module $S$ and some number of copies of the free $R$-module $R$.

Comment: Although very interesting, I'm not really familiar with this machinery. Could you explain more how this makes my problem easier/solves it?

Comment: I've expanded on the reduction. On the other hand, if you are not familiar with the theory of Jordan canonical forms, I emphatically recommend that you do familiarise yourself with it!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Just to follow up and add some more concreteness to my understanding. $M$ is a complex vector space (whose dimension is not necessarily the same as the number of generators for the module $M$). If we hit $M$ with the endomorphism $f$, the image is the subspace $\epsilon M$. $B$ is then the basis for Im$(f)$. What is $B'$ be the basis for? It's not Ker$(f)$? I don't see why $C$ is not the null space. It seems like $B$ is the basis for everything that will died in one hit of $f$ and $B'$ is the basis for everything that will die in two hits. What else is there?

Comment: I should specify, it seems as though $B$ is the basis for everything that will take exactly two hits of $f$ to die and $B'$ is a basis for everything that will take exactly one hit to die. Since Everything is either dead to begin with, or will die in at most two hits of $f$, it seems like $C$ is empty to me.

Comment: Find an example of a module which is $1$-dimensional. What is $C$ then?

Comment: The ring itself is a rank 1, or 1-dimensional module. $B$ will just be $\epsilon\mathbb{C}$ and $B'$ will be $\mathbb{C}$. Thus there is nothing left for $C$.

Comment: I did not say «of rank $1$»: I said «module which is $1$-dimensional» as a complex vector space :)

Comment: So the ring itself is a two dimensional vector space over complex numbers, since we need two complex numbers to specify something in the ring. A module which is a one dimensional complex vector space is $R/(\epsilon)\cong \mathbb{C}$. Action on this by $\epsilon$ kills it, and therefore this is not a free module. I think this is where things became confusing, because I am trying to think of it as a vector space, when it clearly cannot be a vector space since it is not a free module, i.e. isn't torsion-free.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like $R=\mathbb{C}[\epsilon]$ is an Artinian uniserial ring (or "special principal ideal ring") with ideal structure $R\supset (x)\supset (0)$.

It's known the finitely generated modules $^\dagger$ of these rings are direct sums of cyclic modules, and in this case there are only two possibilities that cyclic modules are isomorphic to: $R$ and $R/(x)$.

$^\dagger$ All modules actually, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Let's say an R-module (call it $M$) is isomorphic to $R^r \times (R/(\epsilon))^s$. Then $M$ has precisely $r+s$ generators, right?

Comment: @Pascal'sWager I’m not fresh in the theory of minimal generators, but for a commutative artinian ring I guess it would be true.