# Classification of $k[x]/(x^2)$-modules

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, representation-theory

Let $k$ be a field. How to prove that every finitely generated $k[x]/(x^2)$-module is a direct sum of copies of $k[x]/(x^2)$ and $k[x]/(x)$?

This follows from a more general result by Nakayama on modules over uniserial Artinian rings, but I wonder if there is a direct proof which does not use much theory. Actually the theorem applies to *all* modules, but I am only interested in finitely generated modules here. The tag "representation theory" comes from the interpretation $k[x]/(x^2) \cong k[\Sigma_2]$ when $\mathrm{char}(k)=2$. Thus, the goal is to classify all representations of $\Sigma_2$ in characteristic $2$.

Edit: Sorry, this was a silly question. Since $k[x]$ is a PID, finitely generated $k[x]$-modules have a well-known classification. One just has to look at those killed by $x^2$, and we are done.

Comment: For other readers' benefit: the more general result referred to indicates that in an Artinian uniserial ring, all modules are direct sums of cyclic modules, of which there are only two nonzero ones $k[x]/(x^2)$ and the quotient of this by the ideal $(x)/(x^2)$. The second one is abbreviated above as "$k[x]/(x)$", and could look a bit odd at first without this explanation.

Comment: This is a pretty neat challenge to solve this without the general results about Artinian uniserial rings...

Comment: How do you show the interpretation holds when char k = 2? I don't seem to find the appropriate isomorphism. Thanks. Hopefully user @rschwieb can give some light too. Thanks.

Comment: @21understanding The last paragraph says it all: $k[x]$ is a PID for any field $k$, and the question is trivial using the classification of modules over a PID. It has nothing to do with characteristic.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Classify finitely generated modules over the ring $\mathbb{C}[\epsilon]$ where $\epsilon^2=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/138673/classify-finitely-generated-modules-over-the-ring-mathbbc-epsilon-where)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you are allowed to use. This is a simple consequence of the fact that $A=k[x]/(x^2)$ is an injective $A$-module. If $M$ is any finitely generated $A$-module and if it has an element $m$ with $\mathrm{Ann}\, m=0$, then we get an inclusion $A\to M$, which splits. Thus we are reduced to the case when all elements in $M$ have non-zero annihilator. But, then $xM=0$ and the rest is clear.

Comment: Ah, of course, we can use self-injectivity :) That's not available for general uniserial Artinian rings, and it's quite strong.

Comment: Thank you! I already know that $R/\langle r \rangle$ is self-injective when $R$ is a PID and $r \in R \setminus \{0\}$. (This is quite elementary when we work in the category of f.g. modules.)

Answer (score 7):

Here's an elementary linear algebra proof.

Let $M$ be a $k[x]/(x^2)$-module, and let $T:M\to M$ be multiplication by $x$.

Let $U=T(M)$. Since $x^2=0$, $T(M)\leq\ker(T)$, and so we can choose a subspace $V$ of $M$ such that $\ker(T)=U\oplus V$.

Then we can choose $W$ so that $M=U\oplus V\oplus W$.

Then $T$ induces an isomorphism from $W$ to $U$. Let $\{w_i\}$ be a basis of $W$, so $\{w_ix\}$ is a basis of $U$. Let $\{v_j\}$ be a basis of $V$.

Then $M$ is the direct sum of submodules $V_j=\langle v_j\rangle$, which are isomorphic to $k[x]/(x)$, and $L_i=\langle w_i,w_ix\rangle$, which are isomorphic to $k[x]/(x^2)$.

Comment: Thank you for this proof. I like it.

Comment: Sorry, how can you choose the subspace $V$? If we take $M$ to be $k[x]/(x^2)$ itself, isn't $T(M)=ker T$? I am new in this theory. Thanks for some guidance.

Comment: @HeinrichD Hopefully you can respond too. Thanks.

Comment: @21understanding Yes, if $M=k[x]/(x^2)$ then $U=T(M)=\ker(T)$. So you can take $V=0$. In general, $U$ is a subspace of $\ker(T)$, so it's always possible to choose a complementary subspace $V$ such that $\ker(T)=U\oplus V$.